# dev_appserver returns error "unexpected port response from runtime"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Last week, I have successfully tried the Helloworld example with sdk release 1.7.6 and python 2.7 on Windows XP SP3.  Today it will not run at all and generates this error.

Can anybody help?

```
D:\helloworld>dev_appserver.py d:\helloworld
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:18,187 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates
 to the SDK.
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:19,062 sdk_update_checker.py:272] The SDK is up to dat
e.
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:19,421 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http 
://localhost:1868
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:19,437 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" run
ning at: http ://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:19,483 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
http ://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-03-24 20:16:29,717 http_runtime.py:221] unexpected port response f
rom runtime ['before instance\r\n']; exiting the development server
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:30,546 api_server.py:517] Applying all pending transac
tions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-03-24 20:16:30,546 api_server.py:520] Saving search indexes
```

Comment: Check you do not have any print statements in your code.  If you do they will write to stdout which the new dev server doesn't like as it uses stdin/stdout to talk between the main task and the workers.

Comment: Yes I have a print statement.  The Helloworld example is supposed to print "Helloworld!" in a blank web page.  I am using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: That tutorial won't work with the new dev server, use the old dev server that is copackaged with 1.7.6 SDK

Comment: I will give it a try, but it worked fine a few days ago.  Do you know how to activate the old server.  I found the directory.

Comment: You will find `old_dev_appserver.py` in the same directory as the new `dev_appserver.py` just run it instead.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  The old_dev_appserver.py works for me.  I am just curious, so why did the new dev server worked last week then stopped.

Comment: 1.7.6 SDK was only announced on March 20 (last wednesday) are you sure you where running the 1.7.6 SDK last week ;-)

Comment: Positive.  I cam back snowbirding from Florida on Mar 21 and decided to give web development a try.  Did some research and found the Google App Engine concept.  Downloaded the SDK, started playing and Helloworld worked.  Anyway...  I looked at your profile and it seems that we are following the same path.  I started in 1985 with IBM AS/400, then Oracle DB, I took a break from my Datawarehouse consulting business five years ago.  I don't to return to IT except for my own needs.  I decided to start a sushi franchise and I am looking to create my own dynamic web site .  Is GAE a good choice?

Comment: I found I can generate a similar error (though not exactly the same stack trace but I am running linux) by trying to run the dev server under pypy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you do not have any print statements in your code. <strike>If you do they will write to stdout which the new dev server doesn't like as it uses stdin/stdout to talk between the main task and the workers. You can read more on how the new dev server functions - and how debugging with pdb etc  will have to work</strike>

You can run the old version of the server by instead running old_dev_appserver.py

Answer (score 1):

Could you please file a bug at:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Also, have you added any print statements to the libraries in your Python installation?

Tim Hoffman's response:
"""Check you do not have any print statements in your code. If you do they will write to stdout which the new dev server doesn't like as it uses stdin/stdout to talk between the main task and the workers.""" is not correct. Your application can print to stdout and stderr. In your case it looks like something is printing to stdout *before* your application is loaded.